# Key by value, value by key classes in Java standrad libraries

Tags: java, dictionary

Tell me please, there any methods in standard library for implementation some simple dictionary look like: "a=10,b=11,c=12...". I know about HashMap, but as I know we can`t get key by value, just value by key.

Comment: Could it be "can`t get **key(s)** by value" also?

Comment: There is no meaning of look up by value because it can be duplicated and can result in multiple keys.

Comment: i have alphabet. do you see some alphabet with two equals letters? i hope that java have more ways for this problem without entryset

Comment: How many values do you have in your map? Are key and value both  unique?

Comment: ALPHABET! a=10,b=11...z=.... 1 to 1 unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if key & value are all identify, and 1 to 1, then you can write a class which have 2 Map,
1 Map store key:value, another store value:key, so that you can do search in both way.

Also, if key & value have fixed relationship which could be convert by a function, then you can use that function to convert key & value to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Guava BiMap. Seems what you're looking for.

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html

Comment: They did say the standard library.